# Why is the Microsoft/Cognitive-Speech-TTS Java sample not working?

Tags: java, text-to-speech, microsoft-translator

I tried the Microsoft/Cognitive-Speech-TTS Java sample on GitHub. It gets a new access token, using my Cognitive TranslatorSpeech api key. However, the example fails with this error: 
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://speech.platform.bing.com/synthesize

I have not changed any of the code (apart from api) from the GitHub example here: 
https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Speech-TTS/tree/master/Samples-Http/Java/TTSSample/src/com/microsoft/cognitiveservices/ttssample

Can anyone suggest what the problem may be?

Comment: Believe it or not, just posting this question inspired me to solve it myself. I have been using the TranslatorSpeech api, not realizing that Bing Speech was a separate service. So I signed up for Bing speech, got the api, and it works. All in 10 minutes. Thanks.

Comment: To my dismay, although Bing Speech API now works, it does not support TTS in Dutch, even though Bing Translator (online) supports TTS Dutch. The Microsoft Translator Languages page indicates that Dutch is a TTS language. I guess I don't understand the difference between Microsoft SpeechTranslator and Microsoft Bing Speech. I do not need STT, just TTS. What exactly should I be trying to use? Thanks. Microsoft Translator Languages page: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/languages.aspx